# Highlight graph same vertices multiple circle

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I have a graph on which I want to highlight overlapping subset of vertices with a colored ring of larger radius and different color. So that I can see the vertices with multiple highlights. But with `HighlightGraph` I don't see any such option. This is what I was trying. But these are not rings, and I cannot check the overlaps with it.

```
With[{G = CompleteGraph[8], 
  H = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 8}}, 
  C = {Red, Orange, Cyan}},
  HighlightGraph[G, Table[Style[H[[i]], Circle[], C[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@H}]]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Module[{
  G = CompleteGraph[8],  H = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 8}}, 
  C = {Red, Orange, Cyan}, S = {.05, .03, .01}, pos
 }, 
 pos = AssociationThread[VertexList[G] -> GraphEmbedding@G];
 Show[G, Graphics[ 
  MapThread[{#2, Thick, Thread@Circle[#3 /. pos, Scaled@#1]} &, {S,  C, H}]
 ]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks That worked, Nice But this is not graph anymore, it becomes a graph object.

Comment: @NeelBasu you can still work with original graph, this is for a visualization, or do you need a graph at the end?

Comment: Nope so far this is okay with Graphics. But these are filled circle, Can you make them transparent ?

Comment: @NeelBasu Replace `Point` with whatever you want.

Answer (score 6):

Using a custom `VertexShapeFunction`:

```
ClearAll[vShape]
vShape[h_, c_, s_] := Module[{hc = Thread /@ 
  Thread[h -> (Function[k, {#, Circle[k, Scaled@#2]}] & @@@ Thread[{c, s}])], hr}, 
  hr = #[[1, 1]] -> #[[All, 2]] & /@ GatherBy[Join @@ hc, First]; 
  If[MemberQ[Union@Flatten@h, #2], Through[(#2 /. hr)@#], Disk[#, Scaled[.01]]] &]
```

**Examples:**

```
H = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 8}};
Col = {Red, Orange, Cyan};
S = {.05, .03, .01};

CompleteGraph[8, VertexShapeFunction -> vShape[H, Col, S]]
```

[image]

```
CompleteGraph[8,  VertexShapeFunction -> 
  vShape[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 6}},
 {Orange, Green, Blue, Directive[Thick, Red]}, Range[.01, .04, .01]]]
```

[image]

Comment: With Complete Graph it works fine. But when I was trying this on my actual graph, which is big an rectangular. all these circles came as eclipses. So I removed `Scaled`.